# TFS how to get test step details note?

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

I tried **comment** and **ErrorMessage** Property from **ITestCaseResult**, but no luck. I need to get the tester note from test run.

[image: Test Step Details]

Comment: I am using TFS sdk c# development. Picture depicted was from test manager 2013.